# How to fix "Error creating bean with name"

Tags: java, tomcat

My website is/was working just fine. But I am being forced to upgrade the OS of the servers it runs on, because the newer version of a piece of software I need to upgrade, won't run on the old OS. So, now I am in dependency hell.

So, on a test server, I've upgraded the OS from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04.1 . I was also forced to use a later version of Java from:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

to

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
```

And the version of Tomcat from 7 to 8.

Having fiddled a bit (I started this in January, but have only just been able to get back to it, so I can't remember what exactly, though can search the history for clues if required), I can build my application OK, but it fails at the final hurdle:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 19 seconds Using CATALINA_BASE:
>   /var/lib/tomcat8 Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat8 Using
>   CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/lib/tomcat8/temp Using JRE_HOME:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/ Using CLASSPATH:
>   /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   Using CATALINA_PID:    /root/catalina.pid Tomcat started.
>   --2019-05-28 16:10:16--  http://localhost:8080/ Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1 Connecting to localhost
>   (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting
>   response... 404 2019-05-28 16:10:16 ERROR 404: (no description).

Further investigation reveals:

```
less /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out
```

> 2019-05-28 16:10:06.418 UTC [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
>   failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'embedController' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/playground-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'homeController' while settin g bean property
>   'homeController'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/playground-servlet.xml]: Cannot re solve reference
>   to bean 'execService' while setting bean property 'execService';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'execService': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:326)
>   ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]

It should be abundantly clear by now that I don't have much clue what I'm doing. I have spent the afternoon doing lots of googling and looking at lots of Stack Overflow answers, but nothing seems relevant.

Comment: Spring is not able to create the bean execService for you, because when it tries to instantiate an Object of the class it gets a `ConnectionRefusedException`.

To help you to solve this, we would need to see the class for the bean "execService"

Comment: It starts with `public interface ExecService {`. I know what an interface class is in another language, so is this going to be any help? The class that implements it has 1800+ lines of code. Obviously, I'm nervous of posting source code. I guess I can try an MCVE, but I have so little expertise that it's going to be tough to generate one.

Comment: to be honest, i assume @jspcal answer is the correct direction. Upgrade spring to 5.x or downgrade java is a minimum requirement. after this if the exception still occurs we can disguss  further options ;) :D

Comment: Is it the full exception stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that error comes from Spring. For Java 11 support, you'd also need to upgrade Spring to the latest 5.x version (currently 5.2.x).

You may encounter various compatibility issues when upgrading an older environment to Java 11. Unless you absolutely need to upgrade, you may consider staying on a previous version. Java 8 is still being supported.

Comment: Thank you. I'll investigate. I can't remember why I went for 11.

Comment: I have changed to Java 8. I did go for Spring 5.2.x but had all sort of problems. I toned it down by going for Spring 4.3.24 and got one problem, which I was pleased with myself for being able to fix. I'm now back to where I started with the same error. It's probably better to post a new question. Thank you for your help.